# SSJS Confirmation Dialog before rest of Codes runs behind a button in XPages

Tags: dialog, xpages

I would like to make a confirmation before continue. I mean rest of codes should not run a until a user make a decision (Yes/No). If a user push the button "YES" It should create a new document. If the user chose "NO" nothing should happen.
in this code a confirmation dialog appears that asks "Are you sure to create new Document" 
 My problem is
a new document is already created If the user chose "Yes or no". this codes below does not care answer in the Dialog? Whole code runs then that dialog appears. I think i miss something :(

```
var dateOther = docOther.getFirstItem("TarihBitis").getDateTimeValue();
if (dateOther==null)
{  
    var dlgA = getComponent("dialogTarifeConfirm");
    dlgA.show();
    //Creating New Doc...
    var docNew = database.createDocument();
    docNew.appendItemValue("Subject", requestScope.subject);
    docNew.appendItemValue("fieldName1", viewScope.fieldName1);
    docNew.appendItemValue("fieldName2", viewScope.fieldName2);
    docNew.save();
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. 
Regards
Cumhur Ata

UPDATE 1 : Please find Where i am mixed after the dialog codes does not care the answer both document are created then the dialog will appear on the screen. I think I miss something that I don't know.

```
try 
{
    //Sync backend document with changes made in the frontend document
    var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
    var today:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(@Now());
    var bugun:java.util.Date = new java.util.Date();
    var dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    cn = sessionScope.commonUserName;

    //getCurrnetUserName as String
    var user:String=session.getEffectiveUserName();

    var tKey = doc.getItemValueString("ParentUNID");
    var ParaBirimi = document1.getItemValueString("ParaBirimi");
    var tarifeView:NotesView = database.getView("(viewStandartTarifelerKontrol)");
    var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = tarifeView.getAllEntriesByKey(ParaBirimi);
    var docBuUNID = document1.getDocument().getUniversalID();
    if(document1.isNewNote())
    {
        if (vec.getCount() > 0) 
        {
            var entry1:NotesViewEntry = vec.getFirstEntry();
            while (entry1!= null) 
            {
                var tarifeDoc:NotesDocument = entry1.getDocument();
                var tarifeUNID  = tarifeDoc.getUniversalID();
                var ParentUNID = tarifeDoc.getItemValueString("ParentUNID");
                if (docBuUNID!=tarifeUNID)
                {       
                    var tarifeDocBasDate:NotesDateTime = tarifeDoc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("startDate").elementAt(0);
                    var docBuBasDate:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("startDate").elementAt(0);
                    var days:int = tarifeDocBasDate.timeDifferenceDouble(docBuBasDate) / 86400; 

                    diff = docBuBasDate.timeDifference(tarifeDocBasDate)/86400;
                    var a = tarifeDoc.getFirstItem("endDate").getDateTimeValue();
                    if (a==null)
                    {  
                        if(diff>0)
                        {
                            var a = getComponent("dialogConfirm1");
                            a.show();
                            //If the user say YES FORMA document will be created.
                            var docNew = database.createDocument();
                            docNew.appendItemValue("Subject", viewScope.subject);
                            docNew.appendItemValue("Form","FormA");

                            //If the user say NO FORMB document will be created.
                            var docNew = database.createDocument();
                            docNew.appendItemValue("Subject", viewScope.subject);
                            docNew.appendItemValue("Form","FormB");
                            docNew.save();
                        }
                    }

                }
                var tmpentry = vec.getNextEntry();
                entry1.recycle();
                entry1 = tmpentry;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(e) 
{
    print(e);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the confirm simple action? The user clicking Cancel will cause the action group to stop processing (so group your SSJS into the same action group, after the confirm), clicking OK continues as expected. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_simpleactions_confirmaction_r.html

Comment: It does not work for me :( the action does not start or does not continue with confirmation. Actually confirmation is  middle of codes. I am not sure how to manage together confirmation in my codes. I will update all my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use "this.message"?

A simple example of using it to delete documents could be:

```
<xp:button value="Delete" id="button3"
                                        styleClass="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-xs">
                                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                                            refreshMode="complete">
                                            <xp:this.action>

                                                <xp:actionGroup>

                                                    <xp:confirm>
                                                        <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Are you sure you want to delete this document?"}]]></xp:this.message>
                                                    </xp:confirm>
                                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                                        <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:var id = rowData.getUniversalID();
    var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(id);
    doc.remove(true);}]]></xp:this.condition>
                                                    </xp:actionGroup>

                                                </xp:actionGroup>
                                            </xp:this.action>
                                        </xp:eventHandler>
                                    </xp:button>
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Create a button for opening your dialog:

```
<xp:button id="btnDialogTarifeConfirm" value="Create New Document">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" execMode="partial" execId="btnDialogTarifeConfirm">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dialogTarifeConfirm:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dialog.UIDialog = getComponent("dialogTarifeConfirm");
            dialogTarifeConfirm.show();}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

### 2. Behind your dialogs button `btnCreateNewDocument` your code should be placed:

```
<xe:dialog id="dialogTarifeConfirm" title="Create New Document">
    ...
    <xp:div styleClass="lotusDialogFooter">
        <xp:button id="btnCreateNewDocument" value="YES (Create New Document)">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="lotusForm"
                    execMode="partial" execId="btnCreateNewDocument">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://Creating New Doc...
    var docNew = database.createDocument();
    docNew.appendItemValue("Subject", requestScope.subject);
    docNew.appendItemValue("fieldName1", viewScope.fieldName1);
    docNew.appendItemValue("fieldName2", viewScope.fieldName2);
    docNew.save();}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:link escape="true" text="No" themeId="Link.Action"
            onclick="XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogTarifeConfirm}')">
        </xp:link>
    </xp:div>
</xe:dialog>
```

I hope this helps